# solving "argument requires that `x` is borrowed for `'y`"

Tags: rust

**tl;dr** blocked by "*argument requires that `x` is borrowed for `'y`*"; how can I coerce variable `x` to lifetime `'y`?

Given the following code, I'm blocked when trying to create the `Box` pointer pointing to a reference. I know the referenced object instance lives long enough. However, the rust compiler is concerned it does not.
***How do I tell the rust compiler that `Box::new(&thing)` is valid for the lifetime of the containing struct instance?***

### Code example

This code is essentially:

1. `Things` (a `Vec`), holding multiple `Thing`s
2. counter of `Thing`s (a `HashMap`), holding multiple `Box` pointers to different `&Thing` as keys, a `u64` count as values

(My best attempt at) a minimal example ([rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=beta&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=515d2f2c196087633bbc0b3daac84f76)):

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

type Thing<'a> = (&'a str, usize);
type Things<'a> = Vec<Thing<'a>>;

type ThingsCounterKey<'a> = Box<&'a Thing<'a>>;
type ThingsCounter<'a> = HashMap<ThingsCounterKey<'a>, u64>;

pub struct Struct1<'struct1> {
    things1: Things<'struct1>,
    thingscounter1: ThingsCounter<'struct1>,
}

impl<'struct1> Struct1<'struct1> {
    pub fn new() -> Struct1<'struct1> {
        Struct1{
            things1: Things::new(),
            thingscounter1: ThingsCounter::new(),
        }
    }
    fn things_update(&mut self, thing_: Thing<'struct1>) {
        self.things1.push(thing_);
        let counter = self.thingscounter1.entry(
            ThingsCounterKey::new(&thing_)
        ).or_insert(0);
        *counter += 1;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut s1 = Struct1::new();
    for (x, y) in [("a", 1 as usize), ("b", 2 as usize)] {
        s1.things_update((x, y));
    }
}
```

This results in compiler error:

```
error[E0597]: `thing_` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:24:35
   |
14 | impl<'struct1> Struct1<'struct1> {
   |      -------- lifetime `'struct1` defined here
...
24 |             ThingsCounterKey::new(&thing_)
   |             ----------------------^^^^^^^-
   |             |                     |
   |             |                     borrowed value does not live long enough
   |             argument requires that `thing_` is borrowed for `'struct1`
...
27 |     }
   |     - `thing_` dropped here while still borrowed

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0597`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

**How can I tell the rust compiler "*`&thing_` has the lifetime of `'struct1`*"?**

---

### Similar questions

Before this Question is marked as duplicate, these questions are similar but not quite the same. These Questions address `'static` lifetimes or other slightly different scenarios.

- [Argument requires that value is borrowed for `'static` not working for non copy value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68059435/argument-requires-that-value-is-borrowed-for-static-not-working-for-non-copy)
- [Argument requires that _ is borrowed for 'static - how do I work round this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58436950/argument-requires-that-is-borrowed-for-static-how-do-i-work-round-this)
- ["argument requires that `record` is borrowed for `'static`" when using belonging_to associations with tokio-diesel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63256779/argument-requires-that-record-is-borrowed-for-static-when-using-belonging)
- [(tokio::spawn) borrowed value does not live long enough -- argument requires that `sleepy` is borrowed for `'static`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63347498/tokiospawn-borrowed-value-does-not-live-long-enough-argument-requires-tha)
- [Rust lifetime syntax when borrowing variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70673513/rust-lifetime-syntax-when-borrowing-variables)
- [Borrow data out of a mutex "borrowed value does not live long enough"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083065/borrow-data-out-of-a-mutex-borrowed-value-does-not-live-long-enough)
- [Rust: argument requires that borrow lasts for `'static`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63654640/rust-argument-requires-that-borrow-lasts-for-static)

Answer (score 2):

`thing_` is passed by value. Its lifetime ends at the end of `things_update`. That means, the reference to `thing_` becomes invalid after the end of the function but still be held by the struct, which is certainly should be rejected.

Comment: Thanks @QuarticCat , I thought the parameter declaration `thing_: Thing<'struct1>` would mean `thing_` lives as long as the `Struct1` instance. So I was surprised the rust compiler regards `thing_` as invalid when `things_update` finishes.

Comment: `thing_: Thing<'struct1>` means `thing_` holds a reference to a string and this reference has a lifetime `'struct1`. It doesn't specify the lifetime of itself. Here is a [blog](https://github.com/pretzelhammer/rust-blog/blob/master/posts/common-rust-lifetime-misconceptions.md) that may help you understand lifetime better.

Answer (score 1):

Like many times, actually the compiler is right and you were wrong. The compiler prevented you from use-after-free.

`thing_` *doesn't* live long enough: you pushed *a copy of it* into the vector. It was clear if you'd used a type that isn't `Copy`:

```rust
type Thing<'a> = (&'a str, String);
// ...
```

Besides the previous error, now you also get:

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `thing_`
  --> src/main.rs:24:35
   |
21 |     fn things_update(&mut self, thing_: Thing<'struct1>) {
   |                                 ------ move occurs because `thing_` has type `(&str, String)`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
22 |         self.things1.push(thing_);
   |                           ------ value moved here
23 |         let counter = self.thingscounter1.entry(
24 |             ThingsCounterKey::new(&thing_)
   |                                   ^^^^^^^ value borrowed here after move
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=beta&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=710cd09a7def3e43cbc7d96058223505).

In other case, you would have to first push the item into the vector and then retrieve a reference to the pushed item there, like:

```rust
self.things1.push(thing_);
let counter = self.thingscounter1.entry(
    ThingsCounterKey::new(self.things1.last().unwrap())
).or_insert(0);
```

But in this case [it will not work](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=beta&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1b0cb4632cbd65212b25c28ec728d0dc), and you'll get a long "cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter in function call due to conflicting requirements" error. This is because you're essentially trying to do the impossible: create a self-referential struct. See [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct) for more about this problem and how to solve it.